# Guarantees on STL parallel search algorithms

Tags: c++, stl

Do the parallel versions of search algorithms in the STL (e.g. std::find, std::find_if) guarantee to return iterators to the first element in the range matching the criterion?

The documentation makes no explicit reference to whether this is the case - and in 'C++ Concurrency in Action' there is an implementation that specifically does **not** return the first element.

Comment: It they didn't they would not work as the non-parallell counterparts and therefore be pretty much worthless.

Comment: Do you mean the C++ standard library? If so, there is (currently, as of C++14) no formal distinction between parallel and serial algorithms. The behaviour of the algorithms is well specified, and any departure from that would make an implementation non-compliant. So it really depends on what algorithms you're asking about.

Comment: Yes I mean the standard ones. I assumed they would be the same as the serial versions, but was slightly confused by the book - I guess it's just a simpler example. Many thanks!

Comment: @juanchopanza for future reference, so I can ask better questions, how would I make it more clear I am referring to the C++ standard library other than tagging the question with c++ and STL, and referring to algorithms such as std::find_if?

Comment: @danielgharvey I would just say "C++ standard library". In most cases, it doesn't really matter, but here the wording of the actual C++ standard matters.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't think it is *categorically* worthless. At times, all you're interested is in finding *some* element that fits the predicate, and this could speed things up. FWIW, I thought that this was one indication that the execution policies were not rich enough, and tried to [propose an extension](http://autumn_interleaved.bitbucket.org/technical_specifications.html#synopsis) (which didn't gain any traction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of standard library algorithms<sup>*</sup> such as [`std::find`, `std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is well specified in the C++ standard. As of C++14, there are no exceptions to the specified behaviour for parallel algorithms. This means that hypothetical parallel implementations still need to respect these requirements in order to be compliant.

---

<sup>* From comments, OP means the C++ standard library, and not the Standard Template Library. I make the distinction because the STL may well define a different set of rules.</sup>

Comment: Hang on. find_if in the C++ standard is defined for input iterators. Presumably the parallel version requires something stronger, so it isn't completely equivalent. Not that it matters to me in this case, but makes me wonder what is and isn't guaranteed to be the same between the sequential and parallel versions. I wonder if there is any full specification of the parallel versions? I can't find it.

Comment: @danielgharvey The point is that there is no parallel version in the current standard. A parallel implementation would have to respect the specified semantics.